# Word that describes something that glows with light, but cannot break the barrier of darkness

Tags: single-word-requests

What word could be used to describe a glowing object or mass that though it has a quality of brilliance, does not throw light to illume anything? 
Say, "The mysterious ball ____ with a self-contained light." 
or of a city that though full of lights and vividness cannot extend its glow past the darkness of night?

Comment: Try *sparkles*.

Comment: like a dance of lights that hold a glow only to themselves... could be. good one. But when you think of sparkles one tends not to think of a whole body flowing with inner light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glimmer: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glimmer

May carry a connotation of faintness that you don't intend>

Comment: I like this word for my context; if there is no better one then I'll use this one. Maybe somthing like this, "The city was a show of lights that was felt from within, but beyond the heights of buildings and into the darkness, it cowered to only a glimmer that dared not pry into the outside night."

Answer (score 1):

You might consider, ***shimmer***

> A subdued, tremulous light or gleam.
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shimmer)

Comment: This word I like and also has faint mysterious aspect to it. When applied to an object it seams to vivifie it with a contained glow.

Answer (score 0):

Try illuminates 
"to supply or brighten with light; light up."
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/illuminate
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illuminate

Comment: But the question asked for something that does NOT illuminate.

Answer (score -1):

You understand that if you see the object, it is illuminating *something*, yes? Perhaps it is too faint to illuminate nearby objects or maybe it is non-reflective, but if we perceive the object with our eyes it must emit light.